# scss - syntax throws 'isn't a valid value' error in some places but not others

Tags: sass, gulp, zurb-foundation

I'm experiencing a strange issue with scss (using Foundation but I'm not sure this is a foundation issue)
using gulp-sass v3.7.3 and gulp v3.9.1

```
// 14. Close Button
// ----------------

$closebutton-position: right top;
$closebutton-offset-horizontal: (
        small: .66rem,
        medium: 1rem,
);
$closebutton-offset-vertical: (
        small: .33em,
        medium: .5rem,
);
$closebutton-sizes: (
        small: 1.5em,
        medium: 2em,
);
$closebutton-lineheight: 1;
$closebutton-color: $dark-gray;
$closebutton-color-hover: $black;
```

This block throws the following errors:

```
Error in plugin 'sass'
Message:
    bower_components/myfoundation/scss/_settings.scss
Error: (small:0.66rem,medium:1rem) isn't a valid CSS value.
        on line 349 of bower_components/emerald/scss/_settings.scss
>>         small: .66rem,
   --------^

Error in plugin 'sass'
Message:
    bower_components/myfoundation/scss/_settings.scss
Error: (small:0.66rem,medium:1rem) isn't a valid CSS value.
        on line 349 of bower_components/emerald/scss/_settings.scss
>>         small: .66rem,
   --------^
```

The strange thing is that if I comment out the values in the `$closebutton-offset-horizontal` and `$closebutton-offset-vertical` variables, everything is built with no errors, even though `$closebutton-sizes` uses the exact same syntax:

```
Builds with no errors:
// 14. Close Button
// ----------------

$closebutton-position: right top;
$closebutton-offset-horizontal: (
        //small: 0.66rem,
        //medium: 1rem,
);
$closebutton-offset-vertical: (
        //small: .33em,
        //medium: .5rem,
);
$closebutton-sizes: (
        small: 1.5em,
        medium: 2em,
);
$closebutton-lineheight: 1;
$closebutton-color: $dark-gray;
$closebutton-color-hover: $black;
```

I've expirimented a little and it doesn't seem to have anything to do with using float/whole values or ems/rems

Comment: Try removing the trailing commas on the last item of each map

Comment: Tried with no luck @biggles. I'll note that this syntax is used in multiple places in the file and always includes that last comma.

Comment: @itsGeorge there's nothing wrong with the code as it compiles properly when I tried it. I suspect it's being used somewhere wrongly. The error says its not a valid CSS value. Can you show us the line of code where those variables are being used as values for CSS properties

Comment: sure thing @BlackEnigma,  here's where the variables are used in foundation. https://github.com/zurb/foundation-sites/blob/develop/scss/components/_close-button.scss

Comment: @itsGeorge This is the file I need to see `/emerald/scss/_settings.scss` cos that's where the error is coming from. I need to see where it's being used as a _value_ for a CSS property. Like I stated earlier the code compiled fine. I took a step further while debugging and used it as a _value_ for a property and it threw the same type of error.